# log4j configuration doesn't show messages spring mvc

Tags: spring, tomcat, log4j, weblogic

I work with spring mvc , maven, eclipse juno. I created a dynamic web project.

I want to use log4j to show log messages in the  console and a file. I deployed my project in the server from eclipse. I deployed my project in Tomcat and weblogic. But I don't see my messages neither console nor file. File is created and has server messages but not my messages.

I copied the log4j.xml from a tutorial. My messages are in the controller. My project is a dynamic web project and I put log4.xml in java resources/src eclipse folder.

I don't know because I don't see messages. Is it necessary to configure more steps?

Structure project is

[image]

I added log4j dependencies in pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>PruebaLog</groupId>
    <artifactId>PruebaLog</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

My log4j.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//log4j/log4j Configuration//EN" "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="Appender1" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
       <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
          <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n"/>
       </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="Appender2" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
       <param name="File" value="D:/Logs/SpringMVC2.log" />
       <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
          <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n"/>
       </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <priority value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="Appender1" />
        <appender-ref ref="Appender2" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: `log4j.xml` should be in the standard Maven `resources` folder, not `src`.

Comment: I don't have Maven resources because my project is dynamic web project. I converted my dynamic web project in maven project

Comment: If `'log4j.xml` isn't in your runtime classpath, that could very well explain why you're not seeing any logging output.

Comment: Could you explain me how to put log4j.xml in my runtime classpath?. I work with Eclipse and log4j.xml is in java resources/src dynamic web project folder

Answer (score 0):

Your whole project structure is missing the maven conventions. Java package folders and source should be in src/main/java, resources like log4j.xml in src/main/resources and web files in src/main/webapp. Check the apache maven website for an overview. Also use eclipse to create a sample maven web project using maven archetypes.

Comment: Maven has a philosophy of convention over configuration.  Instead of adding configuration in your pom file to set the src folder to src, you should remove that config and use the conventional src/main and other folder conventions